# ERROR SolrCore org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=228_3187947] unknown field

Tags: solr, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am getting below error on my solr indexer while updating any data to that indexer and also not able to create new indexer due to this error, can anyone guide on this..

Below error is showing for unknown field while field is present in schema.xmll and morphiline file too. And i am also able to this field in Solr console output..

```
ERROR   SolrCore    
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=228_3187947] unknown field 'COSTCENTERID'
    at org.apache.solr.update.DocumentBuilder.toDocument(DocumentBuilder.java:185)
    at org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand.getLuceneDocument(AddUpdateCommand.java:78)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.updateDocument(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:814)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:235)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:164)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:946)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1101)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:702)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:96)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:166)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:136)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:225)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:121)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:190)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:116)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:173)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:106)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:58)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:99)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2259)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:908)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.httpSolrCall(SolrDispatchFilter.java:469)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter$2.doFilter(SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.java:408)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DelegationTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:579)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.java:413)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:610)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:503)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It's telling you that there is no field named `COSTCENTERID` - have you defined a field named `COSTCENTERID`? What do you expect to happen for this value?

Comment: Yes i already defined this field and it is in my schema.xml and morphiline file too. Also i am able to view or data of this field in solr console..

Comment: When ever any data is getting updated in this indexer solr is showing this error in logs, while data of this field is also getting updated in solr. But i am not able to create any new indexer due to this error. Whenever creating new indexer it shows no running processes for that indexer and logs shows this error.